# audioclip still not playing with guns?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GunLaser: MonoBehaviour
{
    AudioSource LaserSound;
    Rigidbody rigidBody;
    AudioSource audioSource;

    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        LaserSound = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    private void RespondToFireInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            audioSource.Stop();
            audioSource.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Audiosource still doesn't work after making changes. I receive no syntax errors now but laser sound still doesn't play when pressing fire/spacebar. Any guidance is appreciated I believe I followed all advice from everyone who provided on my first post about the subject.  If I'm leaving something out please point out.

Comment: nobody should be `playing with guns` :P

Answer (score 0):

Your method is never being called. Call your method inside of `Update`.

```
void Update()
{
    RespondToFireInput();
}
```

Comment: I updated and made other changes but still no sound :/

Comment: All fixed Thank you :)

Comment: @MartinAntonetty if this asnwer solves your question please mark it as "accepted" using the `✔`

Comment: Yes it is I Thank you :)